# Why am I receiving every spam mail twice?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, spamassassin

For about a year now, I have noticed that almost every junk mail I get comes in is duplicated  -- the exact same mail, received at my email address twice, about 3 minutes apart. I've checked for things like email aliases forwarding me root@ or postmaster@, and I've checked to make sure amavis/postfix aren't double-delivering, but I'm pretty sure none of those things are happening.

Below are the headers from one pair of such emails. I've obfuscated my server, domain, and email but everything else (ids, dates, etc) is exactly as received. You can see that these were different message ids received at different times, but otherwise the headers (and the entire body) are character-for-character identical.

```
Return-Path: <anthony.benson@securemail2.com>
X-Original-To: obfuscated@mail.address
Delivered-To: obfuscated@mail.address
Received: from localhost (obfuscated.mail.server [127.0.0.1])
        by obfuscated.mail.server (Postfix) with ESMTP id BF0817D8020
        for <obfuscated@mail.address>; Mon,  6 Mar 2017 11:57:32 -0500 (EST)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at mail.server
Received: from obfuscated.mail.server ([127.0.0.1])
        by localhost (obfuscated.mail.server [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
        with ESMTP id GHCc_GUy3oD4 for <obfuscated@mail.address>;
        Mon,  6 Mar 2017 11:57:32 -0500 (EST)
Received: from securemail2.com (unknown [184.170.244.205])
        by obfuscated.mail.server (Postfix) with ESMTP id E787F7D801C
        for <obfuscated@mail.address>; Mon,  6 Mar 2017 11:57:31 -0500 (EST)
Date: Mon, 06 Mar 2017 11:48:20 -0500
Subject: Bio-Hack - Controlling blood pressure without medication.
Mime-Version: 1
To: obfuscated@mail.address
Message-ID: <JU17538151ZCIV0fL1kK6j2Mg8@postmaster.securemail2.com>
From: Anthony Benson <anthony.benson@securemail2.com>
Priority: Normal
Reply-To:  anthony.benson@securemail2.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="WpMi7Ho6799197a1a304615c60467081a4124a7"


Return-Path: <anthony.benson@securemail2.com>
X-Original-To: obfuscated@mail.address
Delivered-To: obfuscated@mail.address
Received: from localhost (obfuscated.mail.server [127.0.0.1])
        by obfuscated.mail.server (Postfix) with ESMTP id B486C7D8020
        for <obfuscated@mail.address>; Mon,  6 Mar 2017 11:55:36 -0500 (EST)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at mail.server
Received: from obfuscated.mail.server ([127.0.0.1])
        by localhost (obfuscated.mail.server [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
        with ESMTP id 3HWKiYFt8CKb for <obfuscated@mail.address>;
        Mon,  6 Mar 2017 11:55:35 -0500 (EST)
Received: from securemail2.com (unknown [184.170.244.205])
        by obfuscated.mail.server (Postfix) with ESMTP id 90B207D801C
        for <obfuscated@mail.address>; Mon,  6 Mar 2017 11:55:35 -0500 (EST)
Date: Mon, 06 Mar 2017 11:48:17 -0500
Priority: Normal
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="WpMi7Ho6799197a1a304615c60467081a4124a7"
Mime-Version: 1
From: Anthony Benson <anthony.benson@securemail2.com>
To: obfuscated@mail.address
Reply-To:  anthony.benson@securemail2.com
Subject: Bio-Hack - Controlling blood pressure without medication.
Message-ID: <JU22500690ZCIV0fL1kK6j2Mg8@postmaster.securemail2.com>
```

What I'm wondering here is:

1. Is this something wrong with my mail setup, or am I genuinely receiving *nearly every* junk email twice (I'd estimate well over 80% of them come this way)?
2. Is there any way I can make use of this issue to help train spam-assassin that these are junk? (At the least, can I somehow get the second copy of the email to be "more junky" than the first?)

Comment: Looking at the email headers you were sent two emails, one at `11:55:35 -0500 (EST)` and the other at `11:57:31 -0500 (EST)` almost 2 minutes later. They also have different `Message-ID`s

Comment: Possible that you have two entries in their spam database, perhaps the same email address but mistyped with a leading or trailing space character which wouldn't show in your typical email header.

Comment: @Mokubai that was my first thought... is it reasonable to expect that 80% or more of the spam I get is coming from having my email address in a single spam database?

Comment: It's reasonable to expect spammers to share their databases for fun and profit... difficult to say either way though.